# How to pass the select box value as an array using AJAX from one page to another in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
var message = $("#send_message").val();

    var Teaminput = $("#sms_reminder_team").val();
    for (var i = 0; i <Teaminput.length; i++) 
    {
       var team=Teaminput[i];
    }

    var Memberinput = $("#sms_reminder_members").val();
    for (var i = 0; i <Memberinput.length; i++) 
    {
    var members=Memberinput[i];

  }
```

Get 2 varaibles as array members and team

```
var parameter = "message="+message+"&team="+team+"&members="+members;
  $.ajax({
  url: base_url+'ajaxfiles/dir_sendmessage',
  type: 'POST',
  data: parameter,
  success: function(data)
  {
    document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = data; 
  }
  });
```

How to send both array variables using AJAX from current page to "dir_sendmessage".

Comment: do you mean team and members are arrays? then in for loop it should be like  var team[]=Teaminput[i]; instead of  var team=Teaminput[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line

```
var parameter = "message="+message+"&team="+team+"&members="+members;
```

to

```
var parameter = "message="+message+"&team="+JSON.stringify(team)+"&members="+JSON.stringify(members);
```

**Edit: Modify like this too**

```
var team = [];
var members = [];
for (var i = 0; i <Teaminput.length; i++) 
{
   team=Teaminput[i];
}

var Memberinput = $("#sms_reminder_members").val();
for (var i = 0; i <Memberinput.length; i++) 
{
   members=Memberinput[i];
}
```

**Note:** When you add `var` in each line in the loop, it will  declare a new variable. You have to edit like the above code

**After update the code with the `JSON.stringify()` function, you will be able to get the value as an array in you PHP code**

**Ajax will not directly pass `Jquery` array to `PHP`**

Comment: it's working but in dir_sendmsg page it's show only last value which one i select so how can i retrive as a array in second page???

Comment: @BalsaraDhaval, I didn't get what you  mean. What you mean by `only last value` ?

Comment: i have 8 Teams and 10 different Members connected to that particular team now when i pass JSON.stringify() through data of team and member that time i get only one data which one i select last in select box.eg. if i select first STT(id:1) team and then GCC(id:3) team then output will only 3.

Comment: Just alert the variables `team` and `members` in your java script and observe what you are getting.

Comment: After Scope of array i just get one element in alert box and inside of scope i get all elements so how to i define variable as a Public inside of the for loop scope so able to get both variable data?

Comment: @BalsaraDhaval, Scope of array?

Comment: sorry scope of for loop.

Comment: @BalsaraDhaval, I have edited the answer, Please check

Comment: thank you so much sir but problem is same am not able to get all data of team and members as a array...
it is pass only single value nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ideally you should send in JSON format or use array.tostring() ( can avoid this )

But if you have to send it as array you can try following:

```
$.ajax({ 
url: base_url+'ajaxfiles/dir_sendmessage', 
type: 'POST',
 data: {team:team, members: members}, 
success: function(data) { 
document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = data; } });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = $("#send_message").val();
    var teaminputt = $("#sms_reminder_team").val();
    team = new Array();
    members = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <teaminputt.length; i++) 
    {
       var team=teaminputt[i];
    }

    var memberinput = $("#sms_reminder_members").val();
    for (var i = 0; i <memberinput.length; i++) 
    {
    var members=memberinput[i];

    }

    var parameter = "message="+message+"&team="+team+"&members="+members;
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'ajaxfiles/dir_sendmessage',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameter,
        success: function(data)
        {
        document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = data; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#msg-send-btn").click(function() {
      var message = $("#send_message").val();
      var optionsmembers = $('#sms_reminder_members option:selected');
      var members = $.map(optionsmembers ,function(option) {
      return option.value;
      });
```

//---- Using $.map get all selcted data as a an Array.

```
var postData = {
                  message,
                  members
               }
```

//---- For Avoid Json-Stringfy.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: base_url+'ajaxfiles/dir_sendmessage.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data:{myData:postData},
```

//----- And It's Work Perfectly.